# Salesforce marketing Cloud landing page

Tags: marketing-cloud, landing-page

Actually I am new to the marketing cloud and I learned some basic concepts of it.
Now new project of marketing cloud has assigned to me and I just need some help.

Scenario: 
I have to create one landing page which should look like website home page and data about city, Email address should be captured

How will i create landing page? is there any in build functionality or should we do it by coding??

If coding then please guide me.. Many thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have Cloud Pages or Microsites enabled on your SFMC instance?

You can build the template of your current homepage in HTML/CSS/JS as a regular site, nothing out of ordinary. 
To include a lead capture form, you'll need AMPscript or work with API's.

[Marketing Cloud Development Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/index.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your help. We got requirement just before few days. and we haven't got credentials yet. I will let u know if face any issue

Comment: They have mentioned that modules should be reusable, especially the lead gen form should be build in such way so we can reuse that for other lead gen campaign. If i use smart capture form for landing page then is it possible to fulfill the requirement or should we use AMPscript language for the same.

Comment: All the code you write is re-usable if you add them to Portfolio (https://help.marketingcloud.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/portfolio_for_exacttarget_marketing_cloud/getting_started_with_portfolios/supported_file_types/) but the Smart Capture form itself is drag-and-drop type which need to be re-created with for every new form.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Just one more question. If there is any field which is not available in marketing cloud then during Smart capture form there is option "Create new attribute" so can we create using this? Actually on the form we have one field salon details and we want to capture it in marketing cloud..   Please advice

Comment: Yes, that's exatly right. I would advise to read through documentation about Smart Capture functionality to fully understand it's capabilities ( https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/subscribers/smart_capture/ )

Comment: Thanks!! This will really help me as i am very new to SFMC